# Connect flask_restplus with react-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I want to connect `flask_restplus` or `flask_restful` with `react-admin` but my server api flask does not understand a `react-admin` request

```
import React from 'react';
import { fetchUtils, Admin, Resource} from 'react-admin'
import simpleRestProvider  from 'ra-data-simple-rest'
import PostList from './components/PostList';


const fetchJson = (url, options = {}) => {
    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers({ Accept: 'application/json' });
    }
    // add your own headers here
    options.headers.set('X-Custom-Header', 'foobar');
    return fetchUtils.fetchJson(url, options);
}
const dataProvider = simpleRestProvider('http://localhost:5000', fetchJson);

function App() {
  return <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider}>
    <Resource name='posts' list={PostList} />
  </Admin>
}

export default App;
```

Comment: this is english-speaking community , please translate it to eng

Comment: @Alexey Nikonov I want to connect flask_restplus or flask_resfull with react-admin

Comment: the title must be in Eng as well. But nevertheless provide your errors or encountered issues, because it's hard to understand what's going on